Laravel livewire binding checkboxes from array of object
How to bind an array of objects to checkboxes in Laravel Livewire:
The array looks like this:
[{"name":"A","selected":true}, {"name":"B","selected":true}]

My view blade:
@foreach($list as $index => $d)

   <input type="checkbox" wire:model="list.{{$index}}.selected" @if($d->selected) checked @endif>

@endforeach

The problem is when the checkbox is selected on unselected the array is not updated, how to solve this?

Get answer from the GitHub discussion need to use wire.model.live instead of wire.model.
